# catkin - Run CMake only

Tags: catkin, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a simple method to invoke catkin so that it only configures CMake, but does not invoke `make`?

Right now my current solution is to have `make` do a dry-run:

```
catkin_make --make-args -n
```

However, this occasionally results in errors. (Will post them next time I run into them)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81181/catkin---run-cmake-only/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After invoking `catkin_init_workspace` (which creates a toplevel CMakeLists.txt file) you can just use standard `cmake`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2013-09-19**:
Ah, thanks! To make sure I have it right, you would just to `catkin_ws/build/` and invoke `cmake ../src/CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-19**:
Exactly...